# dictionary merging for certain keys

Tags: python, dictionary

So I want to try and merge only certain keys from one dictionary to another so doing

```
a = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5}
b = {'d':2, 'e':4}
a.update(b)
>>> a
{'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3, 'e': 4, 'd': 2} # returns a merge of all keys
```

However say you only wanted the key and value pair 'd':2 and not all of the elements within the dictionary how would this be possible so you get:

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 5, 'b': 3, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know you want to update `a` with `b['d']`, use this:

```
a['d'] = b['d']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got what you're asking. Anyway, if you want to update just some keys on a dictionary with keys from another, you can do:

```
a['d'] = b['d']
```

or, if you want to update multiple keys:

```
for to_update in keys_to_update: # keys_to_update is a list
    a[to_update] = b[to_update]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use following snippet:

```
a = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':5}
b = {'d':2, 'e':4}

desiredKeys = ('d',)

for key, val in b.items():
    if key in desiredKeys:
        a[key] = b[key]

print( a )
```

Sample above will output:

```
{'d': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'a': 2}
```